# Tkinter remove ListBoxvalues by double clicking

Tags: tkinter, listbox

I want to remove a value from my `ListBox` by double clicking.
I don't understand how can I get the value of the `ListBox` item with the Tkinter Event

Here is what I've done so far :

```
import tkinter as tk

def addValuesListBox(listbox):
    for i in range(10):
        listbox.insert(tk.END, i)

def removeValue(event):
    #here i'd like to remove the value to the corresponding listbox value
    print("remove value")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = tk.Tk()
    listbox = tk.Listbox(window)
    addValuesListBox(listbox)
    listbox.bind( "<Double-Button-1>" , removeValue )
    listbox.pack()
    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want.

```
import tkinter as tk

def addValuesListBox(listbox):
    for i in range(10):
        listbox.insert(tk.END, i)

def removeValue(event):
    selection = listbox.curselection()
    print(selection)
    listbox.delete(selection)
    print("remove value")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = tk.Tk()
    listbox = tk.Listbox(window)
    addValuesListBox(listbox)
    listbox.bind( "<Double-Button-1>" , removeValue )
    listbox.pack()
    window.mainloop()
```